# Starting and Stopping loop from thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

so this is a big deal I need to solve. I have my Visual C# application. In this application users enter data and click execute. When they click execute the core method starts in new thread, in that thread and method is one loop. Constantly using Method invoker I am sending updates to the UserForm what the loop is actually doing. e.g. Like this I am updating progressBar in every cicle.

`progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { progressBar1.Value += 1; });`

I got the requirement to add a button in UserForm which stops the loop in that thread and shows what has been done yet. Not quiting application not stopping processes or what ever I only need to jump to that thread and stop the loop.

I was thinking to add a public class with public methods called stop_loop.cs. I was hoping that when I start the program or execute the core method in new thread It will jump to that class and set cancel to = false, and if I click on the stop button it will also jump to that class and set cancel to true. 
In the end at the beggining of every cicle in that loop in that thread it will check if cancel is true. If it is, than it will stop loop and move to the end of the execution.

Like this. Unfortunately I cannot seem to access this class from my core function. Not even Visual Studio is offering me this option. How can I do it ?

```
namespace textboxes
{
    public class stop_loop
    {
        public bool is_canceled;

        public void set_canceled(bool state)
        {
            this.is_canceled = state;
        }
        public bool get_canceled()
        {
            return this.is_canceled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate class for that? Why not just a member variable in the class doing the work?

Comment: read up on CancelationToken, it sounds like what you are doing is the typical usecase

Comment: Check `ManualResetEvent` class described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Just as a note, your code looks like java syntax. You can simply define a property with: `public bool IsCanceled {get; set; }` and remove that variable and those two get and set methods. Simply set it like`IsCanceled = true;` and get it with `var x = yourClass.IsCanceled;`

Comment: Perhaps you can utilize break; with what was mentioned above.

Comment: Good, I used CancelationToken and adjusted for my needs. Last thing is, how to implement this cancelTokenSource.Cancel(); to Button in UserForm, because this doesnt work. private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { cts.Cancel(); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a sample with calculating factorial:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

    Task task1 = new Task(async () => await Factorial(5, token));
    task1.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Type Y to break the loop:");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    if (s == "Y")
        cancelTokenSource.Cancel();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task Factorial(int x, CancellationToken token)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
            return;
        }

        result *= i;
        Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} equals {1}", i, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, I used this and adjusted for my needs. Last thing is how to implement this cancelTokenSource.Cancel(); to Button in UserForm, because this doesnt work.

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }

Comment: I created [gist](https://gist.github.com/ashchuk/8a659310e2a9cb7e695357cd1bf2fad9) with simple app code

Comment: Aschchuk thank you very very much this works well but one more thing, when I cancel the task and I restart it (I am not closing whole application) it stops at the beginning, like the token is not refreshed or something like that. What can be the cause ? Should I discard the token at the end or something ?

Comment: Yep, you shold call `cancelTokenSource.Dispose()` after `cancelTokenSource.Cancel()` and recreate token `cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()` in `void button1_Click` begining

Comment: You should **never** use `async void` like this!  You need to change that to `static async Task Factorial(int x, CancellationToken token)`.  `async void` is a very bad habit to get in to unless you are using it correctly, and one of the *only* correct places to use it is as an event handler. `async` methods need to return `Task` or `Task<T>` in order for exceptions to propagate correctly.

Comment: Thanks Bradley! I refactored answer

Comment: You should probably pass the `CancellationToken` in to `Task.Delay` also, so that cancelling won't have to wait up to 5 seconds to actually apply.

Comment: `Task.Delay` inserted just for _real work_ imitation. I removed it too, but now you not have time to cancel `Factorial` task and see what sample is worked

Comment: Aschuk thank you very very much ! :) now my app works like I want.